# Can I change the 'future releasedate' in iTunes Connect AFTER approval by Apple?

Tags: ios, release, app-store-connect

I want to make sure that I have control over the releasedate of my app. Previously I could release myself but this option has dissapeared... So, I put the releasedate in the future.
Now, if I want to release earlier, after the approval of Apple, can I change the releasedate? I cannot find a clear answer on this question...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes Connect customer support.

Comment: @CarlVeazey The question is about a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession". And it's not easy to get this kind of information from Apple support. So I think the question is valid.

Comment: The consensus on Meta is that it is off-topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131388/would-questions-about-app-store-approval-be-appropriate-for-so

Answer (score 2):

The option hasn't disappeared. It's still there, but only for app updates.
For the first submission you can only specify a date, but you cannot manually release the app.

If you wish to change this date, you can do it from

*iTunes Connect -> Manage Apps -> [YourApp] -> Rights and Pricing*

as specified by the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html).

When instead you submit an update through iTunes Connect you can specify whether it should be released automatically once approved or not.

The rationale behind this mechanism is specified by this note taken from the same [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW24) (emphasis added)

> **Note**: You can use version release control **only for app updates**. **It is not available for the first version of your app** because you already have the ability to control when your first version goes live (using the Availability Date setting on the “Rights and Pricing” page). If you decide that you never want to release a Pending Developer Release version, you can reject your binary to submit a new one. You are not permitted to skip over an entire version.